# How to insert an element in the middle of a list?

Tags: r, list, insert

I have a list with several elements, say 10.

```
testList <- split(1:10,1:10)
```

How to insert a new element in the middle of the list, say at position 3?

The brute force way of looping through all the elements will work, but just wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think the `append`-function is what you are looking for:

```
append(testList, list(x=42), 3)
$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 2

$`3`
[1] 3

$x
[1] 42

$`4`
[1] 4
#snipped....
```

For more complex lists you might find the `modifyList` function in the utils package to be of use. It allows targeted modifications. What it does *not* support is insertions of rows in a dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

Using extraction indices:

```
> testList[5:11] <- c('something', testList[5:10])
> str(testList)
List of 11
 $ 1 : int 1
 $ 2 : int 2
 $ 3 : int 3
 $ 4 : int 4
 $ 5 : chr "something"
 $ 6 : int 5
 $ 7 : int 6
 $ 8 : int 7
 $ 9 : int 8
 $ 10: int 9
 $   : int 10
```

Comment: Note that this does however cause a mismatch between the original names of the list and the contents. `testList <- c(testList[1:4],"something",testList[5:10])` might be safer if this matters.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, good point. Figured names weren't important in this example, but in other situations that could matter a lot.

Comment: +1 for the nice solution! But append function is what I was looking for!!