# How to insert an element in the middle of an unnamed list based on chronological dates

Tags: r, list

I've got a list of lists and am looking for an appropriate method for inserting a new list into this list based on chronological order. Here's an example:

```
my_list <- list(list("text" = list("headline" = "Hello, World!", 
                                   "text" = "This is some text"), 
                                   "start_date" = list("year" = 2015, 
                                                       "month" = "01", 
                                                       "day" = "01")), 
                list("text" = list("headline" = "Hola, Mundo!", 
                                   "text" = "Este es algo palabras"), 
                                   "start_date" = list("year" = 2015, 
                                                       "month" = "01", 
                                                       "day" = "03")))
```

Now, if I want to add a new element into this list where, say, the start_date is 2015-01-02, I'd want to append it into the middle of the list at index 2 and push the 2nd element "down". If the start_date was 2014-12-31 then I'd want it at the very beginning and push everything else "down", and if it was anything after 2015-01-03 I'd want it at the end. Is there a more efficient method for approaching this than the following?

```
new_list_item <- list("text" = list("headline" = "Bonjour le monde", "text" = "ceci est un texte"), "start_date" = list("year" = 2015, "month" = "01", "day" = "02"))
counter <- 0
index <- lapply(my_list, function(elem) {
  date1 <- as.Date(paste(elem$start_date$year, elem$start_date$month, elem$start_date$day, sep = "-"))
  date2 <- as.Date(paste(new_list_item$start_date$year, new_list_item$start_date$month, new_list_item$start_date$day, sep = "-"))
  counter <<- counter + 1
  if (date2 > date1) {
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    return(counter)
  }
})
index <- min(unlist(index)[!is.null(index)])
my_list <- list(my_list[1:(index - 1)], new_list_item, my_list[index:length(my_list)])
```

Especially since the above method adds extra indexing on the list elements (i.e `[[1]][[1]]$text` vs `[[1]]$text`), which isn't ideal. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using named list elements rather than indices? Not sure what you're ultimately planning to do with these data, so perhaps this wouldn't work, but often, when I've got an issue with adding or removing items from a list or data.frame that would mess up my indices, I find that coding by name (the more robust and more reliable way to code anyway) often solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your new_list_item like this (to match the structure of my_list):

```
new_list_item <- list(list("text" = list("headline" = "Bonjour le monde", "text" = "ceci est un texte"), "start_date" = list("year" = 2015, "month" = "01", "day" = "02")))
```

then the following function works:

```
insert_new_list_item <- function(old_list, new_item){
    # Get the date from new_item
    new_item_date <- as.Date(paste(new_item[[1]]$start_date$year, 
                             new_item[[1]]$start_date$month, 
                             new_item[[1]]$start_date$day, sep = "-"))

    # Get a vector of dates from old_list
    dates_vector <- as.Date(vapply(old_list, function(x) paste(x$start_date$year, 
                                                         x$start_date$month, 
                                                         x$start_date$day, sep = "-"),
                             FUN.VALUE = character(1)))

    # Append the date from the new list item and sort
    dates_vector_new <- sort(c(dates_vector, new_item_date))

    # Get the position of the new list item date
    new_position <- which(dates_vector_new == new_item_date)

    # Append the new list item to the list
    if(new_position == 1){
      new_list <- append(new_item, old_list)
    } else {
      new_list <- append(old_list, new_item, after = new_position-1)
    }

    new_list
}

insert_new_list_item(old_list = my_list, new_item = new_list_item)
```

This question also covers the append function: [How to insert an element in the middle of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025695/how-to-insert-an-element-in-the-middle-of-a-list)

Comment: You deserve a medal. I tried to incorporate the append function from the question you linked, but couldn't figure out how to make it work. This is a very nice solution, so thank you!