# how to use append()'s after= parameter to insert a dataframe into a specific position in a list of dataframes?

Tags: r

Say I download a dataset called `econ_dmg.csv`

```
fileUrl <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MichaelSodeke/DataSets/main/econ_dmg.csv"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile="econ_dmg.csv", method = "curl", mode="wb")
df <- read_csv("econ_dmg.csv")
```

I then group the elements as such:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(state, max.net.loss)
```

Next I convert to a list with:

```
df3 <- group_split(df2)
```

Say I wanted to add a random dataframe into this list:

```
newDF <- data.frame(state=c("UT", "UT"), evtype=c("FLASH FLOOD", "WINTER STORM"), max.net.loss=c(900, 900))
newDF <- as_tibble(newDF)
```

Then let's say I wanted to add it **after** subset `df3[[20]]` in the list `df3`. I attempted the following, but failed:

```
df3 <- append(list(newDF), df3, after=df3[[20]][[3]])
```

Please explain what I did wrong in my approach to using the `after=` parameter in the `append()` function.

Many thanks.

Comment: @akrun Can you demonstrate. I do not understand.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read the part of group_split in your data.  Do you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025695/how-to-insert-an-element-in-the-middle-of-a-list)

Comment: @akrun I have reviewed that solution. But that solution only works if the elements are type integer/ numeric. The elements in my list are data frames. Did you run the code?

Comment: I was a bit perplexed by your code because the `after` is giving `df3[[20]][[3]]#[1] 5000` while the `length` of the 'df3' is 72

Comment: @akrun df3[[20]] refers to a specific position in the list, returning the element of that position. df3[[20]][[3]] refers to the 3rd column of that data frame element in that position. I want to place `newDF` after position df3[[20]].

Comment: isn't this `df3[[20]] <- bind_cols(df3[[20]], newDF)`

Comment: @akrun No. But you did give me an idea, using `bind_rows()` instead. I have solved my issue. I will post my solution below once complete. Many thanks again.

Comment: You said to append after the third column.  So, I thought it is to add new columns instead of rows

Comment: @akrun NO. I am attempting to insert a new element of type data frame into a list object containing other type data frame elements. Did you look at the structure of the list object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to add new rows to the data, use `rbind` from `base R` on the specific location of the `list` by extracting the element `[[` and updating (`<-`) on the same list element

```
df3[[20]] <- rbind(df3[[20]], newDF)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem @Akrun. Many thanks.

Suppose I use:

```
df3[[20]] <- bind_rows(df3[[20]], newDF)
```

Then I unsplit groupings with `do.call`

```
df4 <- do.call(rbind, df3) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Then reorder by decreasing order:

```
df5 <- df4[order(df4$max.net.loss, decreasing=TRUE),]
```